# Ubuntu Mercurial remote: *** failed to import extension hgflow: No module named hgflow

Tags: ubuntu, mercurial, clone

I am new to Ubuntu. As I was trying to clone a repository from another machine. It failed due to no suitable response from remote hg. I am not sure what I can do to solve this issue and any help will be much appreciated.

---

jacky@ironmaiden:~/workspace$ hg clone ssh://xinshi@172.16.7.91:/home/xinshi/workspace/
remote: *** failed to import extension hgflow: No module named hgflow
remote: abort: there is no Mercurial repository here (.hg not found)!
abort: no suitable response from remote hg!

Comment: *there is no Mercurial repository here* should give you a hint that your URL you try to clone from is the wrong one.

Comment: I found the solution it should be 
jacky@ironmaiden:~/workspace$ hg clone ssh://xinshi@172.16.7.91 **://home** /xinshi/workspace/ with double slash.